# pull variable from the command (bash)

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a bash script that can pull variables from it's execution.

I really cannot explain this very well, but I want to get a variable from the same bash script.

Let's say in this instance that the script that I wrote is *CMD.sh*.

```
sh ./CMD.sh foobar
      var = foobar
```

and if this is possible, how can I do this in a script?

```
sh ./CMD.sh foo bar fubar
      var1 = foo
      var2 = bar
      var3 = fubar
```

how can I create a script a *bash.sh* script that can pull in the variable from the above and use it

Comment: Your question isn't quite clear. Try writing an actual command line, and point us what is wrong with your solution.

Comment: Can't you first define the variables an then use them in the `CMD.sh` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are talking about [positional parameters](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameters.html#Shell-Parameters).
*cmd.sh:*

```
#!/bin/bash
var1="$1"
var2="$2"
var3="$3"
echo "$var1 $var2 $var3"
```

`$1` is the first positional parameter i.e argument passed to the script.
`$2` is the second positional parameter i.e argument passed to the script.
...and so on...

Now if you run *cmd.sh* like this:

```
./cmd.sh foo bar fubar
```

the output will be:

```
foo bar fubar
```

Answer (score 3):

You could access the arguments you've passed to a bash script as `$1, $2, $3,...`.
i.e.: if you write a script, say `my-script.sh` and inside you write

```
echo $1
echo $2
echo $3
```

And you execute this script like `./my-script.sh firstarg secondarg thirdarg`, then it will print:

```
firstarg
secondarg
thirdarg
```